# How can you setup auto archiving for a document library?

Tags: document, library

I have been tasked with finding a way to auto archive documents in a document library after they reach a certain age. Is this possible within SharePoint?

Answer (score 5):

You could rely on  Information Management Policies and setup a Retention policy to either archive, remove, etc  (http://www.dynamics101.com/2013/03/sharepoint-information-management-policy/ or http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-HA101631505.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

example is provided step by step.

credit to: Peter Kalmstrom.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYj6bhvzYvI.

if link expires, here are the steps that are also credited to Peter Kalmstrom.

**Step 1A**

1.Open Site Contents.

2. Sharepoint Add an App IconSelect add an app and create a new Document Library .

3.Open the original library. From the Library tab, go to Create Column to add a new column for status.

Sharepoint Create Column

4.Select the Type “Choice (menu to choose from)” and enter choice values (in this case New, Ongoing and Expired).

**Step 1B**

1.From Lists and Libraries, open the original library.

2.From the List Settings tab, click List Workflow and create a workflow.

3.Open a summary page for the new workflow.

4.Under Start Options, check all checkboxes.

5.Go to Edit workflow under Customization and set the  Transition to Stage as “End of Workflow”.

6.Press Condition and select If value equals value. Now you will get the text "If value equals value" under Stage 1.

7.Click on the first value and set the return field to the newly created column name. Here it is Document Status.

8.At the place of the second value you will get a dropdown with the Choices values that you set while creating the column. Select the value that you want to use as a trigger for the move to another library, here Expired.

9.Press the Action button and select Copy Document. Now you will find the text “Copy Document in  this library to this library” at Stage 1.

10.Click the first this library and set it to Current Item

11.Set the second this library to the Archive library you have created.

Move Docs in SharePoint Workflow

[image: WORKFLOW SCREENSHOT]

12.Press the Action button and select Delete Item. Now you will find the text “then Delete item in  this list” under Stage 1. Click this list and select Current Item.

13.Click on Publish.

Comment: Please add the steps from that post. If the example is too long, atleast provide a summary. Too many times, these links expire and the question is left unanswered.